# C# - Getting pitch, channel, and timing of notes from Midi file

Tags: c#, midi

I've been downloading and messing about with libraries for hours. I can't find any that can get all the attributes I need. Does such a library exist?

Comment: Maybe, but StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask, as these kinds of questions are considered off-topic. If you find one and have a question about though, feel free to ask!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read MIDI file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845825/how-to-read-midi-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

NAudio is the most popular audio library for .NET and you can use it to read MIDI files as well.

You can read a MIDI file with this syntax:

```
MidiFile mf = new MidiFile(open.FileName, false);
```

And then get the timing, calculate the pitch, check if it is a NoteOn/NoteOff etc.

Here you can find some details:

https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/562256